# Is storing CSRF token in cookie enough to prevent CSRF?

Tags: angularjs, spring, security, cookies, csrf-protection

In order to prevent CSRF, Spring Security and AngularJS uses a method to store the CSRF token in cookie. Then, for each request, the web client sends the same token as a cookie and HTTP header to the server for validation. These come from this blog. https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii#csrf-protection

However, I think that from the other side, the hacker can fake the cookie and HTTP header to send a fake request. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from ASP .net side of CSRF token for validating anti forgery token is, there will be two places where this token is stored. 
1. In the page, which when request is made from angular, we will include this token in the request header.
2. In cookie, which will be automatically picked up by the request when triggered from browser.

In the server side, when the request is received, server will decrypt both the tokens and validates the request if both have a meaningful relation(this relationship is decided in the server with an algorithm) between them.

Now, here, an attacker couldn't figure out those 2 strings at any cost of time because the anti forgery validation algorithm is not disclosed and every time new strings are generated on the go.And second thing is I think attacker cannot directly include the cookie into the request because cookie is picked up from the browser. Their might be tools to do that. But unless the algorithm which is used is not disclosed, attacker could not accomplish a csrf attack.

I think this might be same for the Java spring side.